Using Multiple If Conditions in AWS CloudFormation to Choose Between Mappings for Resource Configuration
I'm working on an AWS CloudFormation (CFN) template where I have mappings for different environments, like EmrSecurityConfigurationCertiPathsTest, EmrSecurityConfigurationCertiPathsDev, and EmrSecurityConfigurationCertiPathsProd. Each mapping contains specific values for different regions.
For example:
> "Mappings": {
>   "EmrSecurityConfigurationCertiPathsTest": {
>     "ap-east-1": {
>       "EmrSecurityConfigurationCertiPath": "arnOfTestAccountApEast1"
>     },
>     "ap-south-1": {
>       "EmrSecurityConfigurationCertiPath": "arnOfTestAccountApSouth1"
>     },
>     ...
>   },
>   "EmrSecurityConfigurationCertiPathsDev": {
>     ...
>   },
>   "EmrSecurityConfigurationCertiPathsProd": {
>     ...
>   }
> }

Now, I want to select a specific value from these mappings based on the deployment environment, which is determined by an input parameter. For instance, if the deployment is in the Test environment, I want to use the values from EmrSecurityConfigurationCertiPathsTest.
How can I use multiple if conditions in my CloudFormation template to achieve this selection based on the input parameter for the deployment environment? Specifically, how do I reference the selected value in other parts of the template, like in an S3 object definition?
I am able to implement the selection of values from two mappings using an if condition in my AWS CloudFormation (CFN) template. However, I'm facing a challenge when I need to choose from more than two mappings based on the deployment environment. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if
Here's what I tried:

I used an if condition in my CloudFormation template to check the deployment environment parameter.
Based on the environment parameter value (e.g., "Test" or "Dev"), I selected the appropriate mapping using the Fn::If function.

What I expected:

I expected that using the Fn::If function with a condition based on the environment parameter would allow me to choose between two mappings successfully.

What actually resulted:

I was able to choose between two mappings using the Fn::If function. However, I'm unsure how to extend this approach to handle more than two mappings effectively.


I believe what you want to use is Fn::FindInMap.
Documentation: { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "MapName", "TopLevelKey", "SecondLevelKey"] }
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html#w9aac34c28c26c13
You'd also want to set the key of the key-value pair to something that CloudFormation can evaluate, like AWS::Region.
Example:
"Mappings": {
    "EmrSecurityConfigurationCertiPaths : {
        "EmrSecurityConfigurationCertiPathsTest": {
            ...
        }
        "EmrSecurityConfigurationCertiPathsDev": {
            ...
        }
        "EmrSecurityConfigurationCertiPathsProd": {
            ...
        }
    }
}

"Fn::FindInMap": (
      "EmrSecurityConfigurationCertiPaths",
      { Ref: "Environment" }, 
      { Ref: "AWS::Region" }
)

